# Cell listener kicking off multiple requests

Tags: ajax, extjs, grid, extjs4

I have an Extjs 4 grid where I'm utilizing the `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` plugin.

I have an `edit` listener on the grid and each cell has a dropdown where a user can select an entry. However whenever an entry is changed, I see many calls to the `edit` listener function, instead of the expected one.

Is there a better way to track changes using the `CellEditiing` plugin?

**Controller:**

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
            'grid': {
                itemclick: this.selection,
                edit: function(plugin, edit) {
                    this.calculateClassification(edit.record);
                }
            },
            ...
            calculateClassification: function(record) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '/calculate/',
                    params: record,
                    success: function(response, opts) {},
                    failure: function(response, opts) {}
                });
            })
    })
}
```

**Grid:**

```
plugins: [cellEditing]
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
});
```

[image: Console Log]

Comment: What does this `this.selection` do and is there always sent the same data in every request?

Comment: try to check `console.log()` in your `calculateClassification()` check how many times it call

Comment: Just put your 'calculateClassification' on the 'select' listener of each combobox